# How to set a counter on login page

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I created a login page and it has a captcha. Now I want to show captcha when user enter wrong username or password. For that I want to add a page item as a counter that has default value = 0, when user enter wrong username or password, counter becomes counter + 1 and when counter >= 1 then login page shows captcha. So what should I do for that?
I have another question:
Is it possible that some processes don't execute when a page item's type is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Never used oracle apex or plsql, dont know how they work, i will assume that PLSQL is close to MySQL if not my bad...

Add Column LoginCount and if Login fails set it to (whatever the value in LoginCount is) +1, if then user manage to login set it back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Create page item ("Application\Shared Components\Application Items");
Create computation ("Application\Shared Components\Application Computations"), set item value to 0;
In login page processing change item value if login is not successful (PL/SQL):

```
:YOUR_ITEM := :YOUR_ITEM + 1;
```

Set Server-side Condition for Captcha (item = value), select your item and value 0.

Comment: I don't want to use Application items. I should use Source and server condition in Page item properties.